# Exporting TFRecords training patches with Google Earth Engine (kernelSize issues)

Tags: tensorflow, training-data, google-earth-engine, tfrecord

I've been using GEE to export some training patches from Sentinel-2 to be used in Python.
I could make it work, by following the GEE guide https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/tfrecord, and using the `Export.image.toDrive` function and then I can parse the exported TFRecord file to reconstruct my tiles.

```
var image_export_options = {
  'patchDimensions': [366, 366],
  'maxFileSize': 104857600,
  // 'kernelSize': [366, 366],
  'compressed': true
}

Export.image.toDrive({
  image: clipped_img.select(bands.concat(['classes'])),
  description: 'PatchesExport',
  fileNamePrefix: 'Oros_1',
  scale: 10,
  folder: 'myExportFolder',
  fileFormat: 'TFRecord',
  region: export_area,
  formatOptions: image_export_options,  
})
```

However, when I try to specify the kernelSize in the `formatOptions` (that was supposed to **"overlaps adjacent tiles by [kernelSize[0]/2, kernelSize[1]/2]"**, according to the guide) the files are exported but the '*mixer.json' doesn't reflect the increased number of patches and I am not able to iterate through the patches afterwards. The following command crashes the google colab session:

```
image_dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(str(path/(file_prefix+'-00000.tfrecord.gz')), compression_type='GZIP')
first = next(iter(image_dataset))
first
```

The weird is that the problem happens only when I add the kernelSize to the formatOptions.

Answer (score 0):

After some time trying to overcome this issue, I realized a not well documented behavior when one uses the kernel size to export patches from GEE.
Bundled with the exported TFRecord, there exists one `xml` file called `mixer`.
It doesn't matter if we use:

```
'patchDimensions': [184, 184],
'kernelSize': [1, 1],  #default for no overlapping
```

or

```
'patchDimensions': [184, 184],
'kernelSize': [184, 184],  #half patch overlapping
```

The mixer file remains the same and no mention to the kernel/overlapping size:

```
{'patchDimensions': [184, 184],
 'patchesPerRow': 8,
 'projection': {'affine': {'doubleMatrix': [10.0,
    0.0,
    493460.0,
    0.0,
    -10.0,
    9313540.0]},
  'crs': 'EPSG:32724'},
 'totalPatches': 40}
```

In the second case, if we try to parse the patches using `tf.io.parse_single_example(example_proto, image_features_dict)`, where image_features_dict equals something like:

```
{'B2': FixedLenFeature(shape=[184, 184], dtype=tf.float32, default_value=None),
 'B3': FixedLenFeature(shape=[184, 184], dtype=tf.float32, default_value=None),
 'B4': FixedLenFeature(shape=[184, 184], dtype=tf.float32, default_value=None)}
```

it will raise the error:

```
_FallbackException: This function does not handle the case of the path where all inputs are not already EagerTensors.
Can't parse serialized Example. [Op:ParseExampleV2]
```

Instead, to parse these records which have kernelSize > 1, we have to consider patchDimentions + kernelSize as the resulting patch size, even though the `mixer.xml` file says on contraty. In this example, our patchSize would be 368 (original patch size + kernelSize). Be aware that for odd kernel sizes, the number to be added to the original patch size is kernelSize - 1.